# Activity doesn't show actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, deprecated, oncreateoptionsmenu

I joined Android Studio and Android App project a few week ago, and I'm trying to create a simple app with ActionBar options.

When I start Android Studio, following Android Dev. Training, I meet always this rendering error:

> Android Studio doesn't found android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity (ecc...)

I resolved this error by setting a different theme. But whenever I try a new project i will do this again and again. First question: there is a way to fix this rendering problem? I meet this problem also in the MainActivity.java, where the ***extends ActionBarActivity*** is deleted with a line, telling me it is deprecated and  advising me to use AppCompatActivity. Should i follow this tip?

Question number two: i read like 100 post on guys who can't show the actionbar in the activity, and I tried everything, but when I link actionbar menu with activity through:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I still can't view the menu I created on the actionbar.
Some images can maybe help me to explain better my problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nPFx.png

And there is the layout of my activity:

http://i58.tinypic.com/oau8ed.png

As you see, there is no icon button i added and no setting button like menu layout show.

Comment: use AppCompatActivity

Comment: Whats the difference between Activity, AppCompatActivity and ActionBarActivity?

Answer (score 4):

`ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated use [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

to avoid this error:

> Android Studio doesn't found android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

#### you have to Download the latest version of the Support Library! and then you can use

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: Why use AppCompactActivity and not Activity? Android Developers Guide should edit his post ?

Anyway, thats my @styles.xml

<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
</style>

</resources>

Comment: is better to use AppCompactActivity for a better support of the action Bar in most of the OS devices.